# ExpandableListView setAlpha not working in the first time

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want only one child to be normal and the other children are transparent. Some groups which aren't expandable may be also transparent as well while expandable groups must be totally opaque. Filling the views works perfect but setting alpha doesn't. In the first time, all items are 100% opaque, when I expand a group, then every items set their alpha what exactly as I want.

It must be work in the first time.

My `BaseExpandableListAdapter` is something like this:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imgContentListThumbnail;
    ImageView imgContentListRibbon;
    ImageView imgTLIcon;
    ImageView imgKilitIcon;
    TextView txtContentListTitle;
    TextView txtContentListDescription;
    ImageView imgContentListDetail;
    RelativeLayout rlThumbnail;
    ImageView imgPreview;
    RelativeLayout rlContentListRoot;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contentlist, parent, false);

        imgContentListThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListThumbnail);
        imgContentListRibbon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListRibbon);
        imgTLIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgTLIcon);
        imgKilitIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgKilitIcon);
        txtContentListTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContentListTitle);
        Fonts.setTypeface(Fonts.BOLD, txtContentListTitle, activity.getBaseContext());
        txtContentListDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContentListDescription);
        imgContentListDetail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListDetail);
        rlThumbnail = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlThumbnail);
        imgPreview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgOnizleme);
        rlContentListRoot = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlContentListRoot);

        convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(imgContentListThumbnail, imgContentListRibbon, imgTLIcon, imgKilitIcon, txtContentListTitle, txtContentListDescription, imgContentListDetail, rlThumbnail,imgPreview, rlContentListRoot));
    } else {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        imgContentListThumbnail = viewHolder.imgContentListThumbnail;
        imgContentListRibbon = viewHolder.imgContentListRibbon;
        imgTLIcon = viewHolder.imgTLIcon;
        imgKilitIcon = viewHolder.imgKilitIcon;
        txtContentListTitle = viewHolder.txtContentListTitle;
        txtContentListDescription = viewHolder.txtContentListDescription;
        imgContentListDetail = viewHolder.imgContentListDetail;
        rlThumbnail = viewHolder.rlThumbnail;
        imgPreview = viewHolder.imgPreview;
        rlContentListRoot = viewHolder.rlContentListRoot;
    }

    final NativeProgramSet nativeProgramSet = (NativeProgramSet) getGroup(groupPosition);
    Course course = null;
    for(Course item : programOnly.getProgramSummary().getCourseList()) {
        if(item.getId().equals(nativeProgramSet.getCourseIdList().get(0))) {
            course = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    //DECIDING THE ITEM TO BE TRANSPARENT
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F6F6F6"));
    if(nativeProgramSet.getId() != null) { //THIS IS EXPANDABLE, AND MUST BE 100% OPAQUE
        rlThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgContentListThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgContentListRibbon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgTLIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgKilitIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtContentListDescription.setText(getGroupDetailContentNumbers(nativeProgramSet, programOnly.getProgramSummary().getCourseList()));
        if(isExpanded) {
            imgContentListDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.accordion_close_icon);
        } else {
            imgContentListDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.accordion_open_icon);
        }

        txtContentListTitle.setText(nativeProgramSet.getName());
        rlContentListRoot.setAlpha(1.0f);
    } else { //THIS HAS NO CHILDREN, MAY BE TRANSPARENT
        rlThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgContentListThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtContentListDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgContentListDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_search_filter_button_icon);

        if(course != null) {
            convertView = fillListItem(true, course, imgContentListThumbnail, imgContentListRibbon, imgTLIcon, imgKilitIcon, txtContentListTitle, txtContentListDescription, imgContentListDetail, imgPreview, convertView);
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                final Course crs = ((NewProgramDetayActivity)activity).course;
                if ((course.getId().equals(crs.getId())) && intro == null) { //THE ITEM IS SELECTED ONE, MUST BE 100% OPAQUE
                    rlContentListRoot.setAlpha(1.0f);
                } else { //THE ITEM IS NO SELECTED ONE, MUST BE TRANSPARENT
                    rlContentListRoot.setAlpha(0.5f);
                }
            }
        } else {
            rlContentListRoot.setAlpha(1.0f);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imgContentListThumbnail;
    ImageView imgContentListRibbon;
    ImageView imgTLIcon;
    ImageView imgKilitIcon;
    TextView txtContentListTitle;
    TextView txtContentListDescription;
    ImageView imgContentListDetail;
    RelativeLayout rlThumbnail;
    ImageView imgPreview;
    RelativeLayout rlContentListRoot;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contentlist, parent, false);

        imgContentListThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListThumbnail);
        imgContentListRibbon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListRibbon);
        imgTLIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgTLIcon);
        imgKilitIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgKilitIcon);
        txtContentListTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContentListTitle);
        Fonts.setTypeface(Fonts.BOLD, txtContentListTitle, activity.getBaseContext());
        txtContentListDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContentListDescription);
        imgContentListDetail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListDetail);
        rlThumbnail = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlThumbnail);
        imgPreview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgOnizleme);
        rlContentListRoot = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rlContentListRoot);

        convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(imgContentListThumbnail, imgContentListRibbon, imgTLIcon, imgKilitIcon, txtContentListTitle, txtContentListDescription, imgContentListDetail, rlThumbnail, imgPreview, rlContentListRoot));
    } else {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        imgContentListThumbnail = viewHolder.imgContentListThumbnail;
        imgContentListRibbon = viewHolder.imgContentListRibbon;
        imgTLIcon = viewHolder.imgTLIcon;
        imgKilitIcon = viewHolder.imgKilitIcon;
        txtContentListTitle = viewHolder.txtContentListTitle;
        txtContentListDescription = viewHolder.txtContentListDescription;
        imgContentListDetail = viewHolder.imgContentListDetail;
        rlThumbnail = viewHolder.rlThumbnail;
        imgPreview = viewHolder.imgPreview;
        rlContentListRoot = viewHolder.rlContentListRoot;
    }

    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Long courseId = (Long) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    rlThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imgContentListThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txtContentListDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imgContentListDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_search_filter_button_icon);

    Course course = null;
    for(Course item : programOnly.getProgramSummary().getCourseList()) {
        if(item.getId().equals(courseId)) {
            course = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    // DECIDING THE ITEM TO BE TRANSPARENT
    if(course != null) {
        convertView = fillListItem(false, course, imgContentListThumbnail, imgContentListRibbon, imgTLIcon, imgKilitIcon, txtContentListTitle, txtContentListDescription, imgContentListDetail, imgPreview, convertView);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            final Course crs = ((NewProgramDetayActivity)activity).course;
            if ((course.getId().equals(crs.getId())) && intro == null) { //THE ITEM IS SELECTED ONE, MUST BE 100% OPAQUE
                rlContentListRoot.setAlpha(1.0f);
            } else { //THE ITEM IS NOT SELECTED ONE, MUST BE TRANSPARENT
                rlContentListRoot.setAlpha(0.5f);
            }
        }
    } else {
        rlContentListRoot.setAlpha(0.5f);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Groups and children use the same ViewHolder as below:

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    public final ImageView imgContentListThumbnail;
    public final ImageView imgContentListRibbon;
    public final ImageView imgTLIcon;
    public final ImageView imgKilitIcon;
    public final TextView txtContentListTitle;
    public final TextView txtContentListDescription;
    public final ImageView imgContentListDetail;
    public final RelativeLayout rlThumbnail;
    public final ImageView imgPreview;
    public final RelativeLayout rlContentListRoot;

    public ViewHolder(ImageView imgContentListThumbnail, ImageView imgContentListRibbon, ImageView imgTLIcon, ImageView imgKilitIcon, TextView txtContentListTitle, TextView txtContentListDescription, ImageView imgContentListDetail, RelativeLayout rlThumbnail, ImageView imgPreview, RelativeLayout rlContentListRoot) {
        this.imgContentListThumbnail = imgContentListThumbnail;
        this.imgContentListRibbon = imgContentListRibbon;
        this.imgTLIcon = imgTLIcon;
        this.imgKilitIcon = imgKilitIcon;
        this.txtContentListTitle = txtContentListTitle;
        this.txtContentListDescription = txtContentListDescription;
        this.imgContentListDetail = imgContentListDetail;
        this.rlThumbnail = rlThumbnail;
        this.imgPreview = imgPreview;
        this.rlContentListRoot = rlContentListRoot;
    }
}
```

I know the code is really complicated but there must be something that I miss. If you can see we can manage to set alpha correctly in the first time of the view appearance. `rlContentListRoot` is the root element of the viewHolder.

Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, I found the solution for my problem.

In XML, animateLayoutChanges was true and this setting was preventing items from being transparent

So my old expandableListView was this:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/elvProgramCourseList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:divider="#ffffff"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp">
```

And the new one is like this:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/elvProgramCourseList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#ffffff"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp">
```